# If P(n) divides Q(n) for all integers n then does P(x) divides Q(x)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $S = \{ f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\mid f(n) \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. 
Let  $P(x), Q(x) \in S $ be polynomials such that for every $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ either $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)} \in \mathbb{Z}$  or both $P(n), Q(n)$ are $0$ . Can we conclude $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \in S$ ?, or do we have a counter example?.
What if we work in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?
[I know that a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $S$ is $x \choose i$ where $i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.]

Comment: The same is true for $P$ and $D=gcd(P,Q)$. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: "Can we conclude $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \in S$" is not what you ask in the title.

Comment: @lhf Why not? $P(x)$ divides $Q(x)$ implies that $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ is a polynomial $R(x)$, and then the condition that $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)} \in \mathbb{Z}$ means that $R(x)\in S$.

Comment: the polynomials $P_i(x)=\binom{x}{i}$ are called Mahler basic, and generate the algebra $A=C(\mathbb{Z}_p\to K)$, algebra of continuous functions from $p$-adic integers to a field $K$. Any element of $f\in A$ is of the form $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\binom{x}{n}$$ so I think that if $P/Q$ is generated by the $\binom{x}{i}$, then...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Apart from the fact that we can't tell directly what $R(n)$ will be on the points where $P(n)=Q(n)=0$. However, the are only finitely many such points, and therefore I think, if $R$ is a polynomial, that it has to evaluate to an integer there as well.

Comment: @Arthur For every such points, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ would be divisible by $(x-n)$, so they would be simplified from the fraction. I thought this meant we could assume such points don't exists, but I may have been a bit too fast...

Comment: @Arthur I'm agree with you, $P$ need to be a constant polynomial

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498764/61691

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $dQ(x)=P(x)A(x)+r(x)$ for some integer $d$, with $A$ and $r$ having integer coefficients, and degree of $r$ less than degree of $P$. Then $P(n)$ divides $r(n)$ for all $n$. But this is impossible unless $r$ is identically zero, since $P(n)$ grows faster than $r(n)$.

Answer (score -2):

If there exist some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $Q(n)$ & $P(n)$ are both zero then $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ is not exist. Hence $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ doesn't belongs to $S$. So for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\in\mathbb{Z}$. so we can't concluded that $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\in S$ until the second either case not omitted.

Comment: I think that in a case like $Q(n) = 6(n-1)(n-3)$ and $P(n) = 3(n-1)$, the quotient is supposed to be interpreted "with cancellation", i.e., $Q(n)/P(n)$ means $2(n-3)$.